# How to get a database column's data type from Parse.com using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, parse-platform

I'm building an admin panel with some basic web I/O using parse.com as the backend with their JavaScript SDK.

I have some predefined columns in my Parse database, with types already specified. I'm using HTML forms and input fields to create a basic admin panel that will allow me to populate the database with some test values.

However, all of the values I'm putting in - even if I leave an input field empty - are being converted into Strings. This causes an error when Parse's database says "no, column X expects a value of type Number, but a String was given."

I don't want to have to go into JS and make if-else statements to cast the input for each input field into the type that's required. This wouldn't be flexible and things would break if I updated the column names or types.

What I'd like to do is find some way to query the Parse database for the types in a column. It'd be awesome if I could say something like the following:

```
var Table = Parse.Object.extend("tablename");
var table = new Table();
var column = table.columnName;
var columnType = table.columnName.getType();    // hopefully would return a String or a numeric code indicating the column's type
```

Comment: sorry I don't use parse.com but if you have access to the rows directly, check out this little utility to help: http://arasatasaygin.github.io/is.js/

Comment: Just noting - I never found the answer to my question, but I realized that it wasn't a problem because I just needed to cast my values into the required data type before sending them in. HTML form inputs automatically become strings - even if the type is 'number' - so you need to cast them in your javascript. At least, that was my workaround.